# comparing two dates. Equal isn't working as well

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, compare, equals

I've got trouble with comparing two dates:
There is short datetime field in database, recorded by Microsoft Access 2002-2003 data extension (#yyyy/mm/dd#). When I tried to compare via operators "greater than" and "less than" it works fine, but when I replaced with the operator "equal" it's giving me an empty result. Here are the queries:

`SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE (Date = #2015.06.11#)` - returns an empty result, but

`SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE (Date > #2015.06.10#)` - is okay. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: how do you know there are any records for that date?

Comment: Date> #2015/06/10# this query gave me result from 11.06.2015 and more.

Comment: there could be precision issue. you can use (Date>=date1 and Date<=Date2) to get equal result.

Comment: Well, this solution doesn't works too. SELECT * FROM `Logs` WHERE  (`Date` > #2015/06/08#) AND (`Date` < #2015/06/12#) - this query returns  records from 08 to 11. What the hell is going on? Equals still is not working as well

Comment: SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE (Date >= #2015/06/11#) AND (Date <= #2015/06/11#) - empty result. No way

Comment: "Date" is a built-in function, it might be confusing your column name with the function.  Try renaming the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date/Time value *#2015.06.11#* includes a time component, which is *12:00 AM*.

If any of your stored values for that date include a time component other than *12:00 AM*, they will be excluded by your `WHERE` clause.

Use a modified `WHERE` clause to retrieve all the rows for your target date (regardless of time of day) and also display the time components of your stored date values:

```sql
SELECT
    l.*, 
    Format(l.Date, 'h:nn ampm') AS time_component
FROM Logs AS l
WHERE l.Date >= #2015.06.11# AND l.Date < #2015.06.12#;
```

Note, for my system locale, *#2015.06.11#* is not recognized as a Date/Time value because of the dot separators.  However, I presume that format is valid for your locale.  If there is any doubt, try with a different separator: *#2015-06-11#* or *#2015/06/11#*

Comment: I got it! SELECT `rdate` FROM (SELECT l.*,  cdate( Format(l.Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') ) AS `rdate` FROM Logs AS l) WHERE `rdate` >= #2015/06/08# AND `rdate` <= #2015/06/10# -works perfectly fine. Thank you guys for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have an issue. Your table just doesn't contain an entry with that date.